# Getting started with DBUnit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit

I am writing integration test for my repository layer that use JPA. However after each test it leaves the database with a lot of rubbish that I want to get rid off when the test is over. I was looking at DBUnit which seems to be able to re-initialize my database. However the thing with extending TestCases seems a little old? I am not able to find any good tutorials explaining how to use it. I am using JUnit 4.10. Are there other frameworks that is better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DbUnit can be used with JUnit 4, without extending any DbUnit base class. See http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/howto.html#noextend for how to do it.

That said, I really dislike XML and like fast tests, so I wrote [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com) to achive similar functionality, with an all-Java solution.

Comment: I think you got a new user of DBSetup :)

Comment: But how do you set it up for working with my MySQL test database that I have configured in Glassfish?

Comment: I guess your tests don't run inside Glassfish, so that is irrelevant. The easiest way is to use a [DriverManagerDestination](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/apidoc/1.0-RC1/com/ninja_squad/dbsetup/destination/DriverManagerDestination.html), and pass the URL, user and password of your test database. If you have a DataSource for MySQL, then use a [DataSourceDestination](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/apidoc/1.0-RC1/com/ninja_squad/dbsetup/destination/DataSourceDestination.html)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Arquillian. I guess it allows to run tests in the container. So you would use JNDI to get a reference to a DataSource, and use a DataSourceDestination wrapping this DataSource.

Comment: Okey, how would you solve populating a table join table with the primary keys of two other tables that you create in the setup when you use MySQL autoincrement?

Comment: And I also get this: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ninja_squad/dbsetup/destination/Destination

Comment: Impose the value of the IDs in your test data set: you want them fixed to be able to execute tests on them. Regarding the NoClassDefFoundError, it's a matter of including the DbSetup jar in the deployed app, I guess. But this is probably an Arquillian problem.

Comment: So you would suggest me to turn of autoincrement in the test database so I can use fixed data? And I have added the Maven dependency.

Comment: AFAIK, if you insert a value other than 0 or null in the autoincrement column, MySQL will insert what you provide, and not autogenerate the ID. You don't need to turn autoincrement off.